# Svelte format text input

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, sveltekit

I'm looking to create a text input that formats the inputted value as the user inputs it. As the formatting function strips additional characters from the string the input value doesn't update. A bit of a contrived example, [repl link](https://svelte.dev/repl/f3afc77e25b9407fa74f727af1926154?version=3.55.1)

```
<script>
    let value = "[hello]"   
    const parse = (value) => value.replace(/[\[\]&]+/g, '');
    let parsed = parse('[hello]');
    const onChange = (event) => {
        parsed = parse(event.target.value);
    };
</script>

<h1>{parsed}</h1>
<input type="text" value={parsed} on:input={onChange} />
```

The onChange function strips the square brackets from the string but the value in the input doesn't update if I type brackets into the input, I assume since they are stripped the value of parsed remains the same so doesn't trigger an update. I thought about putting it inside a key block but then I'd have to track the position of the cursor, is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, and look up two way data binding in Svelte.

```
<script>
    let value = "[hello]"   
    // strips any square brackets from string
    const parse = (value) => value.replace(/[\[\]&]+/g, '');
    let parsed = parse('[hello]');
    const onChange = () => {
        parsed = parse(parsed);
    };
</script>

<h1>{parsed}</h1>
<input type="text" bind:value={parsed} on:input={onChange} />
```